# Editing .bash_profile file not taking effect

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, console

I need to put `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin` to my `~/.bash_profile` file so that mysql from command line works on my system. Please check [mysql command line not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/221566/mysql-command-line-not-working) for further details on that.

I am working on a fedora system and logged in as root user.

If I run `locate .bash_profile` then I get these:-

```
/etc/skel/.bash_profile
/home/sam/.bash_profile
/home/sohil/.bash_profile
/home/windows/.bash_profile
/root/.bash_profile
```

So, I modified the `/root/.bash_profile` file like this:-

from

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

to

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
export PATH
```

But, still the change is not taking effect - Opening a new console and running `mysql` again says `bash: mysql: command not found`.

However running `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin` in console makes it work for that session. So, I am doing something wrong with the `.bash_profile` file. May be editing incorrect one or doing the edit incorrectly.

**Update**

Before doing the above edit, I also tried by just adding `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin` at the end like this:-

From

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

to

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
```

But it didn't work. What am I missing?

Thanks,
Sandeepan

Comment: Does your ~/.bashrc call ~/.bash_profile?

Comment: how do I check that? I am basically new to server related things

Comment: Iain: those commands make .bash_profile call .bashrc, not the other way around.

Comment: Iain: BIG GRIN!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.bash_profile` is only supposed to be run once, by the login shell.  `.bashrc` is the file that's run for each child.

Try logging out and logging in again, then see if your `.bash_profile` changes are picked up.

Just for the sake of chapter and verse, this is from bash's man page:

```
   When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a  non-inter‐
   active  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes com‐
   mands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.   After  reading
   that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
   in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one  that
   exists  and  is  readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the
   shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

   When a login shell exits, bash reads and  executes  commands  from  the
   file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.

   When  an  interactive  shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
   reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.   This
   may  be inhibited by using the --norc option.  The --rcfile file option
   will force bash to read and  execute  commands  from  file  instead  of
   ~/.bashrc.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to logout to apply the changes,

```
# source ~/.bash_profile
```

should apply your changes.